# Reemplazar esto 123456 por esto 000000 en php

Tags: php

hola tengo una pequeña duda quisiera reemplazar una cadena por 0

```
$cadena = '1234567'
```

Comment: Pero si el valor de la cadena siempre será ese (1234567) con poner $cadena ='000000'; ya tienes. Así que no le veo mucho sentido a la pregunta, tuviera mas sentido si el valor de la cadena fuera desconocido... como es entonces?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer uso de la función `str_repeat` que repite una cadena `n` veces, en este caso el numero de caracteres que tiene `$cadena`

```
$cadena = str_repeat( "0" , strlen($cadena) )
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/T0UrVx)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la función [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) con una expresión regular que reemplace cada caracter numérico por un `0`:

```
$cadena = '1234567';
$cadena0 = preg_replace('/\d/', '0', $cadena);
```

Aquí tienes [un enlace de Ideone](http://ideone.com/I6GKDj).

Answer (score 1):

```
$cadena = '1234567'
str_replace('1234567','0000000',$cadena);
```

**Nota:** De esta forma puedes replazar la subcadena '1234567' por '0000000' en cualquier otra cadena diferente de '1234567' también (por ejemplo 'qqs1234567acv').

Comment: para lo que haces ya podias poner `$cadena = "000000";`

Comment: Por supuesto, pero en el caso de que la cadena sea diferente de ''1234567'' no se aplica tu solución, @lois6b

Comment: La pregunta es para la cadena '1234567' específicamente, así que creo que esta respuesta sí se aplica, lo que veo un poco carente de sentido es la pregunta, porque de la forma que esta formulada sí se resolvería como tu dices @lois6b, o sea poniendo $cadena = "000000";